# How to understand the confusing naming conventions of modern Android companies and prevent getting ripped off?

Tags: redmi

Here's the reason for this post and my annoyance -

There is a phone called Redmi 9 whose codename is Lancelot and there is a decent amount of community support for it, TWRP is available as well as some ROMS.

Seeing this I was impressed and ordered it off of [Amazon](https://www.amazon.in/Redmi-Sporty-Orange-64GB-Storage/dp/B08696W3B3). It clearly said Redmi 9 and the same model with the same price is available on [Redmi's official site](https://www.mi.com/in/redmi-9/) as well.

However when I got the phone, enabled USB debugging connected it to my pc and ran adb shell, the name I got in the prompt was cattail and not lancelot!!!

And cattail has next to no community support for rooting and stuff, no TWRP either.

Googling cattail vs lancelot gives a bunch of results and there is a difference in camera alignment in the two phones.

Further while Lancelot is a decent enough phone in itself, cattail is absolutely disappointing. Searching for lancelot on amazon or redmi shows up nothing and when I search "Redmi 9 code name" in any search engine, I got lancelot!! I bought the Redmi 9 believing it was something it was not.

Is Redmi and Amazon straight up lying or am I missing something here? Where is the guide to understanding naming conventions of smartphones? How do I and everyone else who uses Android prevent companies from ripping me/us off?

Comment: Phone manufacturer like Samsung and Xiaomi sometimes create devices that have the same name but are dedicated for a certain area like your cattail for India or Samsung's sepcial devices for the US market. Therefore I would always recommend to check a device database like [GSMArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_9_(india)-10398.php) where the list available variants or link to very similar phones. Comparing both phones allows you to see that they have a different display resolution and chipset (the G35 chipset of the Indian version is even mentioned in the linked Amazon product page).

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20, there's [an article that explains all Redmi 9 variants on Xiaomist](https://www.xiaomist.com/2020/08/ultimate-guide-to-differentiate-all_31.html). The Redmi India's official site and the Amazon India's link show the exact model of Redmi 9 (India) though.

Comment: I assume stuff for lancelot will not work with cattail? I basically got ripped off and I don't like this practice in the least.

Comment: Yes, it won't work. While I sympathize with you **[caveat emptor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)**

Comment: btw the model name of your phone indicates [Poco C3](https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=10482&idPhone2=10398&idPhone3=10278) so i won't give that much on it. cattail is right